# Windows 98 SE and Ubuntu 20.04 Samba issues

Tags: networking, windows, samba, file-sharing

I'm try now for hours to get a connection between my Windows 98 SE Retro PC and my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Notebook. Both are connected to a D-LINK DIR-655 over Ethernet. Both get a IP via DHCP and can ping each other. But can't see and connect to Samba with Windows 98 SE and vice versa.

I crawled a lot through the web but didn't find any useful. In many cases the Samba Server can be seen on the Win98SE machine but can't get access due to the lack of the NTLM auth mechanism. But in my case there is no Samba Server either. I found [this tutorial](https://framebuffer.io/blog/win98-smb) on the web that describes how to configure Win98SE but not Samba. Samba is in my case almost default config'ed. I followed up this standard Samba Config tutorial https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#3-setting-up-samba . I also tried to bind Samba to the interface eno1 (Ethernet) because it's also WiFi in use on the machine. But deactivation or binding doesn't help either. ufw is disabled. Ah and I also tried the "lanman" method but also didn't help. Both machines are in the same workgroup. The username - johannes in my case - is present on Samba and the Samba password is set.

The Ethernet Card in my Retro PC is a "CS-Ethernet Busmaster Premium" ISA Card. E/A, IRQ and DMA are correctly configured. Why an ISA card? Because my board has only 2 PCI slots an they are occupied by a Voodoo2 and a USB 2.0 card. :)

I hope some one can finally help me here.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This … sounds like a Windows problem more than an Ubuntu issue 

Comment: According to the self-answer this is a Windows 98 problem, so this question is off topic at Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed by another community.

```
min protocol = NT1
```

was the key!

Pitty that nobody could tell me that here.

Comment: That is because we do not know anything about windows... you should have asked this on stack. not here.